# Theory notions on exporting bufr data in geotiff format

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, interpolation

I'm trying to export some bufr data from polar satellites/sensors like DMSP, ASCAT, ATMS etc in geotiff image.
When my program rasterizes satellite data (brigthness temperature for example) by converting long/lat coords in pixel coords, I obtain an image with scattered data. I think it's because satellite data are sampled in a not equispaced manner due to the Earth curvature, and then I map this data to an equispaced matrix of points (my tiff).
My question is simple: is my theory right?
I think yes but some online readings put me in doubt.